# Case Insensitive Messages

Tags: java, string

I am using **LanguageBean** (example of LanguageBean available [here](https://github.com/GluuFederation/oxAuth/blob/master/Server/src/main/java/org/xdi/oxauth/i18n/LanguageBean.java)) to show messages in my application's view, I use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to load my `Locale`, and its [`getMessage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.util.Locale-) to get the valid message for the view. The problem is, some of the messages are uppercase, and some are lowercase in my messages file, so I cannot use `.toLowerCase` or `.toUpperCase` when passing the code to `getMessage`, hence sometimes the messages shown in the view are not correct. Is there a way to override `getMessage`, or maybe a work around for this problem?

**EDIT 1**

Example messages (`<key,value>`): <"hello.world", "hello, world!">, <"my.EXAMPLE", "my example">

Example keys: hello.WORLD, my.example

Result: hello, world!      my example

**EDIT 2**

Imagine my view wants to get "hello.WORLD" but my messages contain "hello.world". The resulting message shown in the view is "hello.world". However, what I want to see is "hello, world!" correspondence to the message "hello.world" from the messages, while the key is "hello.WORLD".

Comment: Do you want to change the case of return value of `getMessage` or the argument to it.. ie. `String key`?

Comment: @cswl It doesn't matter which one changes as long as the response is correct.
I edited the original question to provide examples.
I want them both to return hello and world message correctly.

Comment: So you mean you get `"???" + key + "??? not found"`  ?

Comment: You should tell us what is the desire output. Lowercase for everything except first letter of each sentence or what?

Comment: @cswl Something like this. Please read my edit in the original question.

Comment: @user3437460 please read my edit in the original question.

Comment: I am afraid your second edit is even more confusing since now it involves changing the punctuations. Aren't  you just asking a String case issue?

Comment: @user3437460 the messages format is <key,value>, so in my example, it is <"hello.world", "hello,world!">. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link solved my problem:
[Context Sensitive Resource Bundle Entries in JSF Applications](https://dzone.com/articles/context-sensitive-resource-bun)